# Локальный контроль над игнорируемыми файлами

Tags: git, gitignore

Имеется git-репозиторий проекта, некоторые файлы добавлены в *.gitignore* и таким образом существуют только локально. Тем не менее хочется часть этих файлов держать под локальным контролем версий, дабы отслеживать в них изменения и иметь возможность отката в случае чего. Вроде как получаются два отдельных (параллельных) репозитория, но с общими файлами и различными *.gitignore*.

Эти особые файлы - конфиги различных утилит, которые входят в состав ПО. Расположены они по определению в разных местах, создать единый каталог для них не представляется возможным. Состояние конфигов не нужно хранить на сервере и у каждого пользователя они будут разными. Но иногда изменения в этих файлах хочется отслеживать локально и иметь возможность быстрого переключения на ту или иную версию.

Каким образом можно наиболее оптимально контролировать такие файлы?

Comment: *под локальным контролем* — программа *git* в 99% процентах случаев работает **именно с локальным** хранилищем.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а также в 99% случаев не требуется контроль над игнорируемыми файлами.

Comment: и вам надо разворачивать это ПО на сервер?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman нет. ПО не серверное вовсе. Это комплекс из нескольких отдельных приложений, которые тем не менее могут взаимодействовать по сети. Менять конфиги приходится в процессе разработки, отладки и исправления багов.

Comment: а почему не использовать какие-нибудь системы конфигурации и развертывания? ansible, chef, puppet

Comment: @MikhailVaysman это будет как из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: почему? там все достаточно просто и позволяет хранить всю конфигурацию в VCS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предположим у вас есть репозиторий с проектом **main-repo** и репозиторий с файлами, которые существуют только локально **second-repo**. Тогда внутри **main-repo** вы делаете символическую ссылку на файл в **second-repo**. Получается, что **main-repo** этот файл игнорируется, а историю изменений вы храните в **second-repo**.

Вот такая получается картинка

```
.
├── main-repo
│   ├── dir1
│   ├── .git
│   ├── .gitignore
│   └── ignore.txt -> ../second-repo/ignore.txt
└── second-repo
    ├── .git
    └── ignore.txt
```

В **main-repo** файл **ignore.txt** помещен в **.gitignore**, а в **second-repo** отслеживается полностью.

Comment: Вроде бы работает. Неудобство только в том, что нужно создавать ссылку на каждый файл, требующий контроля.

Comment: @alexolut, так создайте ссылку на каталог.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin файлы находятся в разных папках, и к тому же там присутствуют и другие нужные для основного репозитория файлы.

Comment: @alexolut, разжёывываю: создавайте ссылки не на каждый файл/каталог, а объедините все «особые» файлы/каталоги в один каталог, и на него и сделайте ссылку.

Comment: @alexolut можете стоит описать как возникла такая ситуация? почему нужные файлы оказались в **.gitignore**? возможно  есть более эффективное решение этой задачи, но без понимания ситуации сложно подсказать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin обновил вопрос.